# react native firebase logout navigation

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I make a app with firebase authentication. i used a logout button with my menu. when i click this button signout in firebase but navigation not working. This is my logout code.

```
<Button
 primary
 title="Logout"
 onPress={() => {
  firebase
   .auth()
   .signOut()
   .then(
     () => {
       this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
     },
     function(error) {
       // An error happened.
     }
   );
 }}
>
 Log out
</Button>
```

This shows me this error. naviate to page not working.

```
possible unhandled promise rejection. undefined is not an object ( evaluating 'this3.props.navigation')
```

can anyone help me to fix this error.

Comment: Can you also add the code where you're using the `<Button/>` component and if the component is registered in navigation stack?

Comment: i used this button tag in navigationOptions method under headerRight: {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigationOptions` do not have access to `props` and `state` of the component. Therefore you need to access the `navigation` object which it has got access to.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerRight: (
      <Button
         ...
         navigation.navigate("Login");
      >
        Log out
      </Button>
    )
})
```